# Cookieless SessionState & Web.sitemap

Tags: asp.net

When using SessionState with `cookieless=true` option, sessionId value is stored in the url, so modified url looks something like this:

```
http://yourserver/(sessionid)/folder/resource.aspx
```

In this case how do I make ASP.NET SiteMap to work correctly, Is there any possibility to using wildcards while defining `siteMapNode` inside `Web.sitemap` ?

Comment: The **session ID** is stored in the URL - **not** actual session values....

Comment: I don't think it affect the url is it?

Comment: @marc_s, Thanks! for correcting. Any suggestion on making sitemap to work ?

Comment: @krshekhar, When we use cookieless="true", it does affect the url.